# Convert sed One-Liner to perl

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I am using this `sed` one-liner in my `perl` script. However, is there a way (I am sure there is) to do the same job in perl?

Here is my file:

```
$ cat all_log1.txt 
Looking into the table etl_f_gl_balance
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.row_key:
0
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.ledger_key:
1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.gl_account_key:
1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.legal_entity_key:
1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.cost_center_key:
995
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.natural_account_key:
1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.posting_period_fiscal_key:
5
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.posting_period_key:
5
```

And I want the output as below and here is my `sed` solution:

```
$ sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/:\n/: /g' all_log1.txt 
Looking into the table etl_f_gl_balance
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.row_key: 0
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.ledger_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.gl_account_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.legal_entity_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.cost_center_key: 995
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.natural_account_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.posting_period_fiscal_key: 5
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.posting_period_key: 5
```

At the moment, I am not able to get it done in perl no matter what combination of regex I use. And hence, I ended up calling this `sed` command in my `perl` script.

I am not looking for a perl script, but rather a one-liner.

Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Did `perl -pe's/:\n/: /'` not work?

Comment: I won't post the output, but `s2p ':a; N; $!ba; s/:\n/: /g'` is fun: [`s2p` - sed to perl translator](http://man.cx/s2p)

Comment: FWIW, your original `sed` command could be simplified to `'1 ! {N; s/:\n/: /g}'` or `'/^#/ {N; s/:\n/: /g}'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This perl one-liner should work:

```
perl -pe 's/:\n$/: /' file
Looking into the table etl_f_gl_balance
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.row_key: 0
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.ledger_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.gl_account_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.legal_entity_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.cost_center_key: 995
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.natural_account_key: 1020
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.posting_period_fiscal_key: 5
# of -1 values in  etl_f_gl_balance.posting_period_key: 5
```

Comment: `e` switch is required to write commands directly to the command line what is used here for ?

Comment: It is used here for same purpose. Try above command with `-e` and you will know.

Comment: using `-e` prints out nothing and the file also remains unchanged

Comment: @aelor That's a Perl code written inside `'...'`. Its the charm of Perl.

Answer (score 2):

This one will take backup of current file and update it:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\n$/ /g if /^#/gm' all_log1.txt
```

If you want to have output in screen, then use this one:

```
perl -pe 's/\n$/ /g if /^#/gm' all_log1.txt
```

Comment: but your original file has changed . you can open and check

Comment: you can use a `-pe` flag instead if you want to print the result then and there itself